# How get first level of dom images src

Tags: php, dom

is a way to get first value of image src without foreach?

```
$doc->loadHTML($description);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

this is not working `$doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->nodeValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```